# Kotlin compiler reports that "no method 'equals(Any?): Boolean available" with Spring's TypeDescriptor

Tags: kotlin

The Kotlin compiler is reporting an error when performing an equality check on two instances of Spring's `TypeDescriptor`. For example,

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor

fun foo(a: TypeDescriptor, b: TypeDescriptor) = a == b
```

fails to compile with the error message `No method 'equals(Any?): Boolean' available`. `TypeDescriptor` does override the `equals` method, and replacing the `==` operator with `a.equals(b)` works.

I am using Kotlin version 1.3.21.

Comment: That compiles fine for me using Kotlin 1.3.21 and Spring 5.1.2…  Can you give any more details?

Comment: @gidds I'm compiling the code through Gradle using the Spring plugin and dependencies on Spring Boot 2.1.3, Kotlin reflection, the Jackson Kotlin module, and some reactive Spring modules (webflux and data-reactive-mongodb). I'm not sure why these dependencies would matter but they're the only difference I can see.

Comment: I have the same problem with a custom class (i.e. not spring-related afaict) in Kotlin 1.7.10 and 1.7.20.